# What is causing NVARCHAR(MAX) to be limited to 4000 characters using SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Setting up a simple scenario after whittling down my problem I am declaring an NVARCHAR(MAX) parameter in SQL Server 2019. For the sake of space I will omit the 4680 characters, but this can be duplicated on any SQL Box.

```
DECLARE @IDs NVARCHAR(MAX);
    BEGIN
        --I added 4680 characters here but cut it down for question here
        SELECT @IDs = '11240,10677,11128,11183,11248,'
        
    END 
    PRINT @IDs
    PRINT LEN(@IDs)
```

My results are 4000 characters in the SSMS console from the first PRINT line: `PRINT @IDs`. Just moving my cursor to the end of the console line and looking at the character count.

And 4680 characters from the second PRINT line: `PRINT LEN(@IDs)`

What could be causing this? Is there a DBO setting in SQL Server 2019 that needs to be turned on?

Comment: It's not `NVARCHAR(MAX)` that is limited, it is `print`

Comment: To confirm @HoneyBadger 's comment, from [PRINT (Transact-SQL): Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): *"A message string can be up to 8,000 characters long if it is a non-Unicode string, and 4,000 characters long if it is a Unicode string."*

Comment: If you're only doing this for debugging purposes and don't care about things lining up neatly, a quick and dirty (destructive!) print loop is `WHILE @IDs <> '' BEGIN; PRINT @IDs; SELECT @IDs = STUFF(@IDs, 1, 4000, ''); END;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the comments have answered the root cause (the length limit of a single message that can be returned via PRINT). Here is a solution that will return your data set split amongst multiple messages in the same batch.

Please note, this assumes that your IDs are comma separated and wont work without a delimiter.

```
DECLARE @IDs NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @remainder INT;

SET @IDs = 'Long delimited list here'

WHILE LEN(@IDs) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @remainder = CHARINDEX(','/*delimiter here*/,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@IDs,0,4000)),0)
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@IDs,0,4000-@remainder)
    SET @IDs = SUBSTRING(@IDs,4000-@remainder/*+1 to remove the comma starting the new set*/,LEN(@IDs))
END
```